# Error in Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, urdf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-In the tutorial
**http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch**

when I typed the following command `roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf` in the terminal to examine the model, I had the following error

```
... logging to /home/eman/.ros/log/c7aa09c8-aee6-11e3-82a3-f46d04518b4d/roslaunch-eman-K52F-6478.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 279, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 257, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 206, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 121, in _load_config
    self.config = roslaunch.config.load_config_default(self.roslaunch_files, self.port, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 428, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 698, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 670, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 614, in _recurse_load
    self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 240, in _param_tag
    value = self.param_value(verbose, name, ptype, *vals)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/loader.py", line 453, in param_value
    with open(textfile, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'
```

even though,the urdf_tutorial package are found in the following path **filesystem/opt/ros/hydro/share** and contains the urdf file.
when I tried the command `rospack find urdf_tutorial`,it returned the package path **/opt/ros/hydro/share/urdf_tutorial**.
so,it means that ROS can see the package.
**So,my question is; What is the cause of this error?? & why does it return "no such file or directory" ??**

- my distribution is hydro.
- I use Ubuntu 12.10.

please,help.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141466/error-in-building-a-visual-robot-model-with-urdf-from-scratch/) by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-18**:
Did you run roslaunch from within the urdf_tutorial package? Did you run roscd urdf_tutorial before roslaunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To extend a little on the answers by @Maya and @BennyRe: the tutorial explicitly tells you that you should either first `roscd urdf_tutorials`, **or** always provide the full (absolute) path to the urdf files.

From the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch):

```
# All of the robot models mentioned in this tutorial can be found in the urdf_tutorial package.
[..]
$ roscd urdf_tutorial
```

and:

> This launch file assumes that `01-myfirst.urdf` is in the `urdf` subdirectory of the directory that you type the command in. Otherwise, you should say `model:='$(find pkg-name)/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'` where pkg-name is the name of the package that the file is in (single quotes required). All of the example files are in the `urdf_tutorial` package, so if you are in that directory you can run the commands without modification.

It would appear that your current working directory is not the `urdf_tutorial` package, hence the launch fails.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Enter the complete path of the 01-myfirst.rudf file

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks/robot_model_tutorials/urdf_tutorial/01-myfirst.urdf
```

I have the same problem when I try to launch the urdf tutorial from groovy and hydro. This did the fix for me.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@BennyRe @gvdhoorn @Maya

**Thanks a lot for your help.**

- The cause of error was that I didn't
  run `roscd urdf_tutorial` before
  roslaunch.
- The problem has been solved when I :-

  - first, run `roscd urdf_tutorial`.
  - then, run the command  `roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf`.

**It is working successfully now & the cylinder  appears in Rviz as shown in the tutorial.**

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) with karma: 164 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1